# How to change an object with only its reference in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How may I change an object with only its reference in Javascript?

```
var $obj = { original: true }

var $ref = $obj

// Is it possible here to set $obj to {} with only using $ref?
$ref = {} // This doesn't work

console.log($obj)
// => { original: true }
```

Example usage:

```
var $objs = { 
  a: {
    wantsToBeAnEmptyObject: true
  },
  b: {
    wantsToBeAnEmptyObject: true
  }
}

_.forOwn($objs, (val) => {
  val = {}
})
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible here to set $obj to {} with only using $ref?

It's not possible to change *which object* `$obj` refers to using `$ref`, no. You can change the *state* of the object they both refer to (adding, updating, or removing properties), but you can't change *which object* `$obj` refers to. (Note that removing properties from an object de-optimizes it on most JavaScript engines, making subsequent property access much slower. It doesn't usually matter, since even when "slower" modern engines are still very, very fast. But...)

The usual solution to that is to have `$obj` refer to an object with a property that refers to the object you want to be able to replace:

```
var $obj = {obj: { original: true } };
// --------^^^^^--------------------^
var $ref = $obj;
$ref.obj = { replaced: true };
//  ^^^^
console.log($obj.obj.replaced) // true
```

Comment: Thank you. This is probably the best way to proceed

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `delete` keyword to remove keys from an object, which I think would accomplish what you're looking for.
In your example something like

```
Object.keys($ref).forEach(key=>delete $ref[key])
```

would do the trick

Comment: Bit of a leap, but that *could* be what the OP wants (although it's not really what they asked).

Comment: I'd say it's exactly what OP asked for. It's a way of changing an object using only a reference to that object. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question though.

Comment: Well, again, it *may* be, they may not have asked quite what they want. `ref = {} // This doesn't work` is pretty clearly replacing something with a **new** object, not just deleting properties from the existing one.

Comment: Thank you. I've been having this same problem in many shapes and sizes, so it's useful to know several tricks to overcome it